# Delphi XE5 Interbase query

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, interbase

I have a Listview with LiveBindings to a DB. I have `FetchOptions RowSetSize` set to 20.
Query:

```
Select * from "MyDB" where "Name" LIKE "%&FieldList%' AND "Tag'=1
```

If I set `FetchOptions` to `onDemand` LiveBindings works but I get 3000 items and it is very slow.

If I set `FetchOptions` to `Manual` LiveBindings does not work but I can, through FetchNext, get my 20 items. But I have to populate the `ListView` myself.

So, is there any way to have onDemand but only get 20 items at a time?

Comment: You need to provide some code to be helped some way.

Comment: You may wish to provide the code where you're actually setting your options as well.

Comment: Not sure exactly what options you are looking for. I have properties for FetchOptions set as:

CursorKind = ckDefault;
Mode = fmonDemand (or fmManual)
RecsMax = -1
RecsSkip = -1
RowSetSize = 20
Unidirectional = false

Just let me know what other options would be pertinent.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use rows to limit the query:

```
select * from employee rows 10 to 20
```